# Is there a way to restore a deleted job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I accidentally deleted a job in Jenkins... Is there a way to restore it?
I have the files on disk but I don't remember the configurations and despite trying to reconfigure, I prefer to try to restore it, if i can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using duplicity and duply as backup system. It works like a sharm! And then the "Reload configuration from disk" option.

Comment: I wonder how this is different from my answer from three years ago, since in the question it was mentioned that files are already in the disk, so no need for extra backup system.

Answer (score 12):

If you have the files (including the job) and can copy it to correct location, there is "Reload configurations from disk" option in "Manage Jenkins" page.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Comment: also consider keeping [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) for future

Comment: You may want to start running [Jenkins Backup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Backup+Plugin) or [Periodic Backup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PeriodicBackup+Plugin) Plugins.